# “As the paper is at 9:30 I will try to reach around.”Is this sentence makes any sense?

Tags: grammaticality

In the above sentence I wanted to tell my colleague that I will reach around 9:30. So I wrote this sentence but I am confused whether I had conveyed him that message correctly or not.

Comment: reach around? is this a phrasal verb, or a verb followed by a modifier? and I really can't understand your question or your sentence

Comment: No, it doesn't make any sense.  What are you grabbing for that has 9:30 in the way of reaching it?

Comment: Do you mean you want to arrive somewhere in time to hear a presentation of a paper?

Answer (score 0):

I would break this into two parts: "The paper starts at 9:30 AM. I will try to be at (the presentation area?) around that time."